# Populating select options dynamically based on previous choices

Tags: arrays, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am having issues prepopulating select boxes based on an array.  Now I am passing my view an array which looks like the following

```
array:4 [▼
  "folder1" => array:1 [▶]
  "folder2" => array:2 [▶]
  "folder3" => array:1 [▶]
  "folder4" => array:1 [▼
    "product1" => array:1 [▼
      2016 => array:1 [▼
        "March" => array:1 [▼
          0 => "image1.png"
        ]
      ]
    ]
    "product2" => array:1 [▼
      2015 => array:1 [▼
        "June" => array:1 [▼
          0 => "image1.png"
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

Now for this part I am only interested in folder4.  I plan on having 4 select inputs.  The first one should display the products.  The products are folders within the root of folder4.

So in the example above, this select should show product1 and product2.

The second select should show the years.  The years are folders within the products.  The third select should show the months.  The months are folders within the years folders.

The last select should show the image names.

All of this will probably need to be within the foreach loop.  Reason I say this is because if they select product2 in the first select box, the next select box should only have the year 2015, not the year from product1 folder.  This is where I am at this moment in time, but it is quite a way off

```
<select class="selectpicker" name="productType">
    @foreach($fileData as $type => $product)
        @if($type == "folder4")
            @foreach($product as $name => $year)
                <option value="{{ $name }}">{{ $name }}</option>
            @endforeach
        @endif
    @endforeach
</select>
```

At the moment I am getting htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given.  This select should display product1 and product2.  Also, have do I make the other select options dynamic based on what has been previously chosen?  So if they choose product 1, the next select box should display the year 2016 only.

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you familiar with ajax requests?

Comment: yes, but why would this matter in this case?

Comment: You can do ajax request based on what you select and get the next select values or you can do as @Kjell said.

Answer (score 0):

This logic should be implemented in the client. So dump all the necessary data in a json into your webpage and then have a javascript or other code render the select elements on your webpage based on selections.

Doing this on the server is a possibility, but a very old school and tedious one...

Comment: Sorry, slightly confused, could you elaborate please?

Comment: Nowadays Laravel / Serverside is not the common place to solve your issue. Have laravel echo the array data as a json to a javascript script element, like: ```<script>var mySelectData = {{ json_encode($fileData) }};</script>``` and from there you need to create some kind of javascript that picks up the data and generates the select input in the browser of the user.